# Kendo UI ListView pagination not set to initial page(first page)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, listview, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with the Kendo UI ListView pagination. When the ListView changes, the previous set page will not change in listview. I have to make the initial page ie. page 1

I'm using MVC razor control

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<M.Models.HomeModel>()
        .Name("listView")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("listingtemplate")
        .Events(e => e.DataBound("listviewDataBound"))
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("M_Read", "Home").Data("queryParameters"));
            dataSource.PageSize(12);
            dataSource.ServerOperation(false);
        })
        .Pageable()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change "Pageable" to this:

.Pageable(pageable => pageable.Refresh(true))

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `dataSource.ServerOperation(false);`, so paging can be done server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var grid= $("#grid_name").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.read(); // perhaps without this line
grid.dataSource.page(1);
```